# How to prevent file stacking in Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to fix this, it happens not because of an Extension:

[image]

Comment: Is the `Explorer › File Nesting` preference disabled?

Comment: @MaartenDev i was right writing the answer. `explorer.fileNesting.enabled` was some-why enabled from the workspace. you can post it as an answer since you sent it too. ty regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour can be controlled by the vscode `Explorer › File Nesting` preference.

In your case you probably want to disable it.

[image: File Nesting setting]